# Why do my MAX6675 boards keep going crazy?

Tags: esp32, emi-filtering

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a simple ESP32 dev board based setup connected to two (going to be three soon) MAX6675 breakout boards. The ESP32 is powered by a 12V DC adaptor connected to its extension board.

Two of them are connected to (cheap) probes to measure temperatures of up to mid 200°C but only the tips are exposed to those high temperatures.

I've used them with different ESP32 based boards and keep getting either crazy high temperatures, 0°C or they'll work for a few batches (they're used in a coffee roaster with average roasting times of 12 - 13 minutes) and then hang.

The ESP32 interfaces with the laptop via Bluetooth but I get this problem when connected via USB too.

I've checked the probes again and again everytime I have issues with a multimeter on thermometer mode and the probes are reporting the right temperatures so it's not them despite their cheapness.

There's quite lot of noise from a VFD but I have an EMI meter to check and the ESP32 and MAX6675 boards are at least 50cm away where EMI is not high.

I'm planning to order some 10nF capacitors soon and perhaps have all the male Dupont ends soldered to a strip board but what else may be causing me to be in this endless war with electronics?

Comment: Welcome! Please post schematic/block diagram of what you have and show with a photo how it's connected. What's your power supply and decoupling situation?

Comment: Are the thermocouples grounded-junction?

Comment: Since the max6675 uses 2 data/clock lines, and many libraries simply toggle GPIO pins to achieve that, they are prune to miss-toggle if the CS pin of the max6675 is not used correctly.

Comment: Also those modules can not be trusted since it is not clear if they use original parts or not. The original MAX6675 is over $10 (at mouser, for 1 piece) while the whole module similar to the ones you use are less than $2 on aliexp.

Comment: My sketch was written specifically to use MAX6675 boards and thermocouples. It's a pretty straightforward and simple sketch but I'm no coder. How difficult would it be to change it to use MAX31865 boards and RTDs because I already have two of those boards on hand.

Comment: And yes, the thermocouples are grounded.

Comment: If the VFD motor cables are not shielded, you’ll need more 50cm to escape the noise created. Use proper VFD rated shielded motor cables correctly terminated to avoid nasty noise issues due to the VFD. Your ‘EMI’ meter sounds suspect.

Comment: My VFD's power cables also go through a EMI filter.